# Spring Security OAuth2 check_token endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to setup a resource server to work with separate authorization server using spring security oauth. I'm using `RemoteTokenServices` which requires `/check_token` endpoint.

I could see that `/oauth/check_token` endpoint is enabled by default when `@EnableAuthorizationServer` is used. However the endpoint is not accessible by default.

Should the following entry be added manually to whitelist this endpoint?

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/check_token").permitAll();
```

This will make this endpoint accessible to all, is this the desired behavior? Or am I missing something.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 21):

You have to

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception
{
   oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");    
}
```

For more information on this ::

[How to use RemoteTokenService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250522/how-to-use-remotetokenservice)

Comment: Wouldn't "isAuthenticated()" be better than "permitAll()"?

Comment: I have written this because he is trying to achieve this in his above code.

Comment: @DaveSyer as per my understanding checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()") will open the endpoint for authenticated users. Then what is the need to again define http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/check_token").permitAll();

Comment: No need, as far as I am aware (assuming I understand the question).

Answer (score 10):

Just to clarify a couple of points, and to add some more information to the answer provided by *Pratik Shah* (and by *Alex* in the related thread):

1- The `configure` method mentioned is overridden by creating a class that extends `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    @Configuration
    public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws     Exception {
            clients
                    .inMemory()
                    .withClient("ger-client-id")
                    .secret("ger-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                    .scopes("read", "write");
        }
    }
```

2- I suggest reading [this Spring guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server) explaining the automatic configuration carried out by Spring Boot when we include the `@EnableAuthorizationServer` annotation, including an `AuthorizationServerConfigurer` bean. If you create a configuration bean extending the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` as I did above, then that whole automatic configuration is disabled.

3- If the automatic configuration suits you just well, and you JUST want to manipulate the access to the `/oauth/check_token` endpoint, you can still do so without creating an `AuthorizationServerConfigurer` bean (and therefore without having to configure everything programmatically).

You'll have to add the `security.oauth2.authorization.check-token-access` property to the `application.properties` file, for example:

```
security.oauth2.client.client-id=ger-client-id
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=ger-secret
security.oauth2.client.scope=read,write

security.oauth2.authorization.check-token-access=permitAll()
```

Of course, you can give it an `isAuthenticated()` value if you prefer.

You can set the log level to DEBUG to check that everything is being configured as expected:

```
16:16:42.763 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.e.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource - Adding web access control expression 'permitAll()', for Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
```

There is no much documentation about these properties, but you can figure them out from [this autoconfiguration class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth2-boot/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/authserver/AuthorizationServerProperties.java#L28).

One last thing worth mentioning, even though it seems to be fixed in latest Spring versions, I just submitted [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1544) in the [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) project; it seems that the token_check functionality is enabled by default if you add a trailing slash to the request:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/oauth/check_token/?token=fc9e4ad4-d6e8-4f57-b67e-c0285dcdeb58
{"scope":["read","write"],"active":true,"exp":1544940147,"authorities":["ROLE_USER"],"client_id":"ger-client-id"}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three POST parameters, namely client_id (user name), client_secret (password corresponding to the user name), token (token applied for), client_id, client_secret are different from the parameters in the /oauth/token interface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StH2u.png)

Answer (score 1):

First, config token access expression:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer securityConfigurer) throws Exception {
    securityConfigurer
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
            .addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(checkTokenEndpointFilter());
}
```

Then, we need define a filter to process client authentication:

```
@Bean
public ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter checkTokenEndpointFilter() {
    ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter filter = new ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter("/oauth/check_token");
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    filter.setAllowOnlyPost(true);
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: i follow the code above ,the "authenticationManager" is @autowird which comes from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManagerBean(),but the filter used for 
 oauth/token org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer#clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter is http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class) .these two authenticationManager are not the same one. so when i post data to "/oauth/check_token" get error like {"error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "Bad client credentials"}  dont know why they are not same