# Spring oauth2 server, can not validate token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I generate JWT token from spring boot oauth2 server, but when I want to validate this jwt token using `'http://auth_server/oauth/check_token'` endpoint,I send post request to this endpoint with jwt in authorization header and I get **401 - unauthorized http error code**.

The result that I get from server:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-03-19T16:28:39.999+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/check_token"
}
```

Why oauth server returns 401?

Here is my implemenattion of oauth server:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsServiceImpl clientDetailsService;

        private String privateKey = "private key";

        @Value("${jwt.accessTokenValidititySeconds:43200}") // 12 hours
        private int accessTokenValiditySeconds;

        @Value("${jwt.authorizedGrantTypes: authorization_code}")
        private String[] authorizedGrantTypes;

        @Value("${jwt.refreshTokenValiditySeconds:2592000}") // 30 days
        private int refreshTokenValiditySeconds;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
                clients.withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {      
            TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
            tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
              Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }


        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
           JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
           converter.setSigningKey(privateKey);
           return converter;
        }


        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
            return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        }

        @Bean
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found that `GET` request should be sent to `http://server.com/oauth/check_token?token=[access_token]` with `client name` and `password` in `authorization header` to check access token validity. Below is the postman example:

[image]

Comment: Change `checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticqted()")` to `checkTokenAccess("permitAll()")` should work

Comment: we all know that `checkTokenAccess("permitAll()") ` works ,but its unsafe!,`isAuthenticated()`; which is more secure than opening it up. Any client wanting to check token will have to supply their client credentials . we need use Basic Authorization  header.

Comment: When `allowFormAuthenticationForClients` is called ,framework add a filter called `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter`, we can send set `client_id` and `client_secret` via query param to retrieve a access_token from `/oauth/token`. Since `/oauth/check_token` has beed set to `checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticqted()")`, I want to let `/oauth/check_token` supports form submit also.

Comment: so I add a customized `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` according [filter for check_token endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36806173/5382024) but it does not work, I find that the ` @Autowired AuthenticationManager authenticationManager` is different from `http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class)`. the autowird authenticationManager's providers list does not have the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` ,but `ClientDetailsUserDetailsService` is in `DaoAuthenticationProvider`  .so my filter will always get ` {"error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "Bad client credentials"}`

Comment: NOTE: username should be clientId, the password should be ClientSecret with the basic authorization. Thanks for answer